# Debugger to print every line of code accessed in python

Tags: python

Is there an option in pdb or some other python debugging tool to print on screen/print to file every line of code that is being accessed ? I am going through some huge amounts of code so copying pasting by hand is tedious. I am wondering if someone could give me tips on how to do this in python or tell me if there are existing tools that do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want a code coverage tool. [Try coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage/), which will tell you which lines have been executed.

Taking a look at the example in the documentation, it can display which lines were executed: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/sample_html/cogapp_test_cogapp.html

Take a look at the ['reporting' and 'annotating' areas of the docs](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/cmd.html#cmd-reporting) for info on how to get the most suitable output for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, how do I use coverage to tell me which lines are executed? THe tutorial seems to provide code coverage as a % , how do you see which lines?